# React: update URL anchor when scrolling to a section with this anchor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, anchor

I am creating a single page react website where I have a header navigation which has links to different sections. If I click on a section, it links to an anchor (in URL like `#section-1`) and adds the class `active` to the element in the nav.

Now I want also want that when I scroll from `section-1` to `section-2`, it updates the anchor in the URL to `section-2` and also removes the class `active` from the first link and adds it on the second link. How can I achieve this?

For the link elements in the nav, I use `Nav.Link` from `react-bootstrap 2.5.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this functionality in your single-page React website, you can follow these steps:

1. Set up your header navigation component with links to different sections. Each link should have an onClick event handler to handle the scrolling and class update.
2. Create a state variable in your component to keep track of the active section and initialize it with the default section.
3. Implement the onClick event handler for each link. In the event handler, update the active section in the state and scroll to the corresponding section.
4. Add a scroll event listener to your component to track the scroll position and update the active section accordingly.
5. In the scroll event listener, calculate the scroll position and determine which section is currently in view.
6. Update the active section in the state based on the scroll position.
7. Add a useEffect hook to listen for changes in the active section state variable and update the URL anchor accordingly.
8. Add a useEffect hook to listen for changes in the URL anchor and update the active section accordingly.

Here's an example implementation to help you get started:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Header = () => {
  const [activeSection, setActiveSection] = useState('section-1');

  const handleLinkClick = (section) => {
    setActiveSection(section);
    scrollToSection(section);
  };

  const scrollToSection = (section) => {
    const element = document.getElementById(section);
    element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = () => {
      const scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
      const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
      
      sections.forEach((section) => {
        const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
        const sectionHeight = section.offsetHeight;

        if (
          scrollPosition >= sectionTop - 50 && // Adjust the offset as needed
          scrollPosition < sectionTop + sectionHeight - 50 // Adjust the offset as needed
        ) {
          setActiveSection(section.id);
        }
      });
    };

    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleUrlAnchorChange = () => {
      const sectionFromUrl = window.location.hash.substr(1);
      setActiveSection(sectionFromUrl);
    };

    window.addEventListener('hashchange', handleUrlAnchorChange);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('hashchange', handleUrlAnchorChange);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.location.hash = activeSection;
  }, [activeSection]);

  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a
            href="#section-1"
            className={activeSection === 'section-1' ? 'active' : ''}
            onClick={() => handleLinkClick('section-1')}
          >
            Section 1
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a
            href="#section-2"
            className={activeSection === 'section-2' ? 'active' : ''}
            onClick={() => handleLinkClick('section-2')}
          >
            Section 2
          </a>
        </li>
        {/* Add more links for other sections */}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

In this example, the active section is tracked using the activeSection state variable. When a link is clicked, the handleLinkClick function is called, updating the active section and scrolling to the corresponding section. The scroll event listener calculates the scroll position and updates the active section accordingly. The URL anchor is updated with the active